# How to assign the user making the request to a foreign key field in Django models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm currently working on a web app similar to discord. I'm trying to set the user who is sending the request to create the server as the owner of the server so that the only thing he wants to enter is details like -  name , icon and description. This is my model for server:

```
class Server(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="server_owner")
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    member = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="servers", through='ServerMember')
    icon = models.FileField(
        upload_to=server_icon_upload_path, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        is_new_server = self._state.adding
        if is_new_server:
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)

            try:
                member_role = Role.objects.create(
                    name="member",
                    server=self
                )
                server_member = ServerMember.objects.create(
                    user=self.owner, server=self)
                server_member.role.add(member_role)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error creating 'member' role: {e}")

        if self.id:
            existing = get_object_or_404(Server, id=self.id)
            if existing.icon and existing.icon != self.icon:
                # Delete the old icon
                existing.icon.delete(save=False)

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

serializer:

```
class ServerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Server
        fields = '__all__'
```

I've tried to override the perform_create function but it didn't work:

```
class ServerCreateView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Server.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ServerSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated] 

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

This was the error I was getting when I was testing the apis  :
response

```
{
    "owner": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hey, can you please share the error you’re getting and also your ServerSerializer

Comment: So exactly *what* is not working? What is happening instead?

Comment: {
    "owner": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
} , this is the problem I'm facing

Comment: Can you confirm that you’re sending a post request with the right data? Your post request should have a body like {“owner”: “owner_id”}

Comment: @Temi,  I understand that . But what I am trying to do is that I want to create server without taking that owner: "" input and setting up the person who's sending the request to be the owner

Comment: Hi @TomXavier, could you also include the `ServerSerializer` to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`perform_create` is never called because the validation fails before that.

Either remove the `owner` field from validation (for example by excluding the field from the serializer), or supply a value for that field in the serializer's initial data so that validation succeeds.